# MongoDB CodeIgniter connection issues

Tags: mongodb, database-connection

PHP-8, CodeIgniter V-3 , DLL install for php-8 that is php_mongodb.dll  in extension folder and enabled in PHP.ini file as well as - given below screen shot of phpinfo still code show error
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MongoDB\Client" not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\miles\conntest.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\miles\conntest.php on line 11**  can some plz help me out this problem
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solutions for this using composers,  and updated to php8 and mongodb 1.9 and by using supporting libraries i got the success.